# Clicking link to replace current frameset contained in current window

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have following link in a.aspx file:

```
<a href="a.htm" target="iframe">A</a>
```

I want to set link from a.aspx.vb page according to what person is viewing the page. 
How can i change this so that if user clicks on link it will replace current frameset contained in current window with a url provided according to user?

Or in another way:

How will i replace href code in aspx page by giving it value from aspx.vb page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make your current link accessible to the code-behind (your vb file) or use an .NET WebControl.

To make your HTML control visible to your code-behind, you need to add `runat="server"` and an ID:

```
<a href="a.htm" target="iframe" runat="server" id="myALink">A</a>
```

Then in your code-behind, you would access the control with the ID you gave the control earlier:

```
myALink.Href = "b.htm";
```

You could also use an [ASP HyperLink control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx):

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="a.htm" Target="iframe" runat="server" Id="myALink" />
```

And set it in the code-behind:

```
myALink.NavigateUrl = "b.htm";
```